# Subgraph induced by cycles that include some subset of edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to solve the following (non-homework) problem:

Given a directed graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, and a (non-empty) subset $S$ of the graph's edges.

Construct the *minimal* subgraph $H$ of $G$ that has the following property: every cycle in $G$ that contains at least one edge from $S$, is also in $H$. Note that $H$ may contain cycles that contain no edges from $S$.

In case $S$ has only a single edge, this problem can be easily solved with a single depth-first search. This means that for arbitrary sizes of S, we could construct said subgraph for each individual element of S, and simply take the union of all the resulting subgraphs. This has a complexity of $O(m^2)$.

I'm wondering if it is possible to come up with an algorithm that beats this complexity. That is, anything better than $O(m^2)$. Something tells me this should be solvable in $O(m)$ with a single DFS as well, but I'm not sure how.

**Edit:** Changed the question slightly to get rid of a contradiction, the question now asks to construct the *minimal* subgraph that satisfies the stated property.

**Edit:** My current (non-formal) approach to (hopefully) finding a linear-time algorithm is to run a DFS, starting at the tail $t$ of an arbitrary edge from S. During the search, back edges indicate potential cycles that should be included in the result. We keep track, per vertex $v$, of both the *deepest* (highest pre-order) edge in $S$ that is in the DFS tree rooted at $v$, and the *highest* (lowest pre-order) edge in $S$ that lies on the path from $t$ to $v$. When visiting a back edge $e$, from these two numbers we can decide whether the cycle introduced by the DFS tree and $e$ needs to be included in the result. If it is included, we mark the tail of $e$.

The tail of a non-back edge to a *marked* vertex is marked as well.
If all vertices have been visited, let the partial result be the subgraph induced by marked vertices. If there is an edge missing in the result, it must be a back edge in the completed DFS. Therefore, we post-process the back edges and use the "lowest" and "highest" indices (see above) of edges of $S$ to determine a posteriori whether they should be included in the result.

Now, this is not an algorithm yet, just a rough idea. I'll try to work this out and test it on a large number of test cases, but there might be a few obvious errors in the reasoning outlined above. If you spot an error, please let me know :-)

Comment: Why $H = G$ is not a solution?

Comment: You're right, let me extend the question. A cycle in $G$ that does not contain an edge from $S$ should not appear in $H$.

Comment: But then you can have 3 cycles $A$,$B$,$C$ in $G$ such that $S$ contains one edge from each, but if you include all three in $H$, then you will also include a fourth cycle $D$ which is also in $G$, but $D \cap S = \varnothing$. I don't understand.

Comment: Changed the question again to take care of this. Subgraph $H$ should be minimal.

Comment: Have you tried anything based on [biconnected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) (like: take the biconnected components that contain any edge of $S$)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that will work, though maintaining a "lowest level" for each vertex sounds useful. I'm currently looking at doing a post-processing step on the back edges found during the DFS. By comparing the indices of the vertices in the pre and post traversal with the indices of the vertices incident with edges from S, one may identify whether the back edge should be included in H. I've tried to explain this idea in an edit I made to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm:**

1. Calculate the biconnected components in $O(m)$ time.
2. Remove from $S$ any bridges (i.e. take care of $K_2$'s).
3. Set $H$ to be the union of biconnected components that contain at least one edge of $S$.

**Why it works:**

$(\Rightarrow)$ Any 2-vertex-connected component has the following property: between any two vertices there are 2 vertex-disjoint paths that connect them. In other words, any two vertices belong to some cycle. So take any edge $e \in S$ and add a new, dummy vertex $v_e$ in the middle of $e$. There are two vertex-disjoint paths between $v_e$ and any other vertex in that component, so each vertex of the component belongs to some cycle containing $e$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose there is a cycle that contains $e \in S$. This cycle belongs to some biconnected component. Since the edge $e$ belongs to a cycle, it cannot be a bridge, hence we will include that biconnected component into $H$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Nice, that seems to do the job! I think bridges can be identified during step 1, so it's two passes over the edges. Great, thanks!